# SmtpClient.Send() complains of incorrect no of overloads when passing in MailMessage object

Tags: c#

I have this code written in .NET 4.0 using VS2010 Ultimate Beta 2:

```
smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

smtpClient is a reference to SmtpClient (I have the relevant references added), and likewise for mailMsg (is MailMessage) - there are no errors stating anything like check for missing assemblies.

However, I keep getting an error saying that I have the incorrect no of overloads, when SmtpClient takes either a MailMessage object or the To address, From address, Subject, etc.

Why doesn't this code work? Totally confused.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: Is that a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: no reason why it shouldnt, can you give more code, that might help.

Comment: Just guessing, haven't used .NET 4 before. 

Up until .NET 3.5 there are *two* MailMessages, `System.Web.MailMessage` and `System.Net.MailMessage`. Perhaps there is a conflict there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different `MailMessage` classes : `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`, and `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage`. The one in the `System.Web.Mail` namespace is obsolete, and is not compatible with `SmtpClient`. Make sure you're using the correct class, perhaps you have a `using System.Web.Mail` clause in your code

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear - you are not using correct arguments for the Send method.

Here is something to help you:

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
    message.From = new MailAddress(textFrom.Text);
    message.To.Add(textTo.Text);
    message.Subject = textSubject.Text;
    message.Body = textBody.Text;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    client.Host = textHost.Text;
    client.Port = Int32.Parse(textPort.Text);
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textUsername.Text, textPassword.Text);

    client.Send(message);
}
```